# Андроид Студио. Как установить New Virtual Device (т.е. которого нет в списке AVD Manager'а)?

Tags: android, android-studio

В частности, Sony Xperia z1 compact g8441.

Для эмуляции. В списке предлагаемых его нет.

Comment: в ручную создавать устройство с аналогичными характеристиками

Comment: А чего Genymotion не возьмешь? Можешь еще Firebase tisting lab попробовать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В том списке темплейтов на самом деле очень мало устройств, там Nexus и Pixel. И редкие конфигураторы специально для тестов. 
Действительно ответ у вас в вопросе, создавайте новое AVD с характеристиками, которые вам необходимы. Всё будет попадать в папку .android/avd, сможете импортировать на другие рабочие места или поделится с тестировщиками например.

Comment: А где-нибудь можно найти такие уже готовые сборки-предложения разных устройств?